# How do I define the python code right, so python can interpret it correctly?

Tags: python

I get following error message with my python code.
*File "/home/ken/Programming/temp.py", line 20
try:
IndentationError: unexpected indent*
I have defined my code apparently badly, but I can't figure out what the issue is.
Here is the code. Can someone help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector, sys, MySQLdb, Adafruit_DHT, datetime, time, multiprocessing
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode

pin = 2
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22

def messaure():

    config = {
      'host':'**************',
      'user':'********',
      'password':'**********',
      'database':'**************',
      'client_flags': [mysql.connector.ClientFlag.SSL],
      'ssl_ca': '/home/ken/shared/Cert/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem'
     }

     try: 
         connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
         if connection.is_connected():
            db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
            print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select database();")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print("You're connected to database: ", record)

          #except Error as e:
          #   print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
            while True:
               humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
               temperature=(round(temperature,2));
               humidity=(round(humidity,2));
               if humidity is not None and humidity >= 0.0 and humidity <= 100.0 and temperature is not None and temperature > -100.0 and temperature < 150.0:
                  mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO weather(temp, hum, station) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')"""
                  cursor = connection.cursor()
                  record = (temperature, humidity, 1)
                  cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, record)
                  connection.commit()
                  print("Record inserted successfully into table weather", temperature, " ", humidity)
                  cursor.close()
                  with open("/home/ken/shared/Measurement/values.txt", "r") as r:
                     value = r.read()   
                     delay = int(value.strip()) * 60  
                     print("The delay is: ", delay)
                     time.sleep(delay)
      except mysql.connector.Error as error:
                 print("Failed to insert record into table {}".format(error))
      finally:
         if (connection.is_connected()):
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

def viewstatus():

     config = {
       'host':'*******',
       'user':'*****',
       'password':'**********',
       'database':'**********',
     }

     try:
         connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
         if connection.is_connected():
            db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
            print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select database();")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print("You're connected to database: ", record)

            #except Error as e:
            #   print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
            while True:
               humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
               temperature=(round(temperature,2));
               humidity=(round(humidity,2));
               if humidity is not None and humidity >= 0.0 and humidity <= 100.0 and temperature is not None and temperature > -100.0 and temperature < 150.0:
                  mySql_insert_query = """UPDATE showinfo set temp ='%s', hum='%s's where id ='1')"""
                  cursor = connection.cursor()
                  record = (temperature, humidity, 1)
                  cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, record)
                  connection.commit()
                  print("Record inserted successfully into table weather", temperature, " ", humidity)
                  cursor.close()
                  print("The delay is: ", delay)
                  time.sleep(300)
       except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to insert record into table {}".format(error))

     finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
           connection.close()
           print("MySQL connection is closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=messaure)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='p', target=viewstatus)
    p1.start()
    p.start()
```

I have tried to defined the code right, so python would interpret it in the right way.

Comment: Your indent is 5 spaces instead of 4 Try changing everything to four spaces and see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: In Python, the indentations must be consistent. Check if you are using the same indentation in all your lines. Sometimes it is easy to confuse spaces and tabs.